# Serial half duplex communication in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have connected two machines through Rs232 half-duplex communication. How can I control RTS/CTS signals through  software or minicom tool in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

See this post on how to toggle RTS or set RTS/CTS hardware handshake in Linux: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/manually-controlling-rts-cts-326590/

If you're using Python look at http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/